# Where do i find source code in wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, backend

I have a website in wordpress! There is a picture on the front page that I need to change I found the code that needed to be changed through chrome inspect but can't find it in cpanel's file manager to actually change it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the page is made in WPBakery Page Builder and thus shouldn't require any source code editing. If you open that page for editing (and start the backend editor if it's not loaded), you should find it in there somewhere.